# How to echo/redirect large text to hdfs put?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to write some text into a file on HDFS through pyspark by using the following:

```
command = (" echo '{0}' | HADOOP_USER_NAME=admin hadoop dfs -put - "+root+"/configs.txt").format(dump)
os.system(command)
```

`dump` is a string variable.
`root+"/configs.txt"` file path
Now , the issue I am facing is that when length of `dump` string is small, the file `configs.txt` is written without any hiccups , but when `dump` is a bit large, 12132 characters to be exact (the string I want to write) , I get an empty file.

What's going on here?
Is there a limit on the size of text? Can I tweak it?

Comment: Why do you tag this with `pyspark`? You're not using it, though maybe you should. Or maybe use the Hadoop API directly, rather than creating a subprocess?

Comment: Ohh that tag was a mistake! How can I use pyspark for this, please elaborate..? dump is a json dump, which I need to write in file. Tried pydoop, the action runs forever , I am on hue.

Comment: This is raw Python code, not Pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can echo a string and put an inputstream.

I think you should write a file, then put that

```
with open('config.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(dump)

command = "HADOOP_USER_NAME=admin hadoop dfs -put {} {}/configs.txt").format('config.txt', root)
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Works ,thanks man! Is this something I should have been able to easily think of? I am new to hdfs.

Comment: It's just standard usage of `hdfs put`, so should be easy, IMO. I don't think there is a way to avoid creating a local file. You may want to remove the file after the put command, though